# Something wrong with the quotations

Tags: php

Sorry I'm new here, after you asked, I have added the full code: And I know my code is bad :)

```
if ((($_FILES["image_name"]["type"] == "image/gif")
   ($_FILES["image_name"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   ($_FILES["image_name"]["type"] == "image/png")
   ($_FILES["image_name"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")))
  {
  $year = date('y');
  $month = date('m');
  $date = date('d');
    if(file_exists('./uploads/'.$year)){ 
        if(file_exists('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month)){
            if(file_exists('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date)){ 
                $target_path='./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date.'/'.$_FILES["image_name"][‌​"name"];
            }
            else{
                mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date);
            }
        }
        else{
            mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month);
        }     
}
else{
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year);
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month);
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date);
}
  if ($_FILES['image_name']['error'] > 0)
    {
    echo 'Return Code: ' . $_FILES['image_name']['error'] . '<br />';
    }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'],
      './uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date.'/'.$_FILES['image_name']['name']);
      $target_path='./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date.'/'.$_FILES["image_name"][‌​"name"];
      }
  }
```

The **$target_path** variable should print like this:

> uploads/13/03/15/image_name.jpg

but it prints:

> s/13/03/15/image_name.jpg

What's wrong?

Comment: Please use line breaks to make that more readable.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried `$target_path='./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date.'/'.$_FILES["image_name"]["name"];` ?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to output the variable, there is nothing in the above code that would indicate why this is happening. Also note that `$_FILES["image_name"]["name"]` is set by the client, and is completely useless to you in every way due to security considerations.

Comment: I believe I tried everything, But I will try this again

Comment: Just tested your code, and it works like it should...

Comment: I tried your exact code both on CLI and in the browser, and it works as you'd expect (and hope). Are there any other potential circumstances? (preprocessing, etc)

Comment: @DaveRandom I added the full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, an important note on file uploads in general: The `type` and `name` keys are unsafe to use. This is because they are defined by the client, and they are a potential mechanism for injecting malicious code into your site. Consider what would happen if I set the file name to `../../../../../index.php`, or if I set the MIME type to `image/gif` but uploaded a PHP file instead?

Next, an important note on image uploads specifically: You cannot trust image data uploaded by the client. It is also possible to embed malicious code in something that *looks* like an image. You need to copy the pixel data out of file and create a new one. This is usually accomplished with the GD extension.

Next, on `mkdir()` - it has a third argument, if you pass `true` to this third argument it creates the directory tree recursively, so you don't need to create each level in a separate operation. Also note that (like many things) it is possible for `mkdir()` to fail, if this happens it will return `false`, and you should check for this.

Now, to answer the actual question (and ignoring the aforementioned security issues for a moment), here is how I would simplify your code:

```
// Configuration
$allowedTypes = array(
    "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/pjpeg"
);
$baseDir = './uploads';

// Check file was uploaded successfully
if ($_FILES['image_name']['error'] > 0) {
    exit('Return Code: ' . $_FILES['image_name']['error'] . '<br />');
}

// Check file type
if (!in_array($_FILES["image_name"]["type"], $allowedTypes)) {
    exit('Invalid file type: ' . $_FILES['image_name']['type'] . '<br />');
}

// Check/create target directory
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', date('y-m-d'));
$targetDir = $baseDir . '/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day;
if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
    if (!mkdir($targetDir, 0644, true)) {
        exit('Failed to create destination directory<br />');
    }
}

// Store the uploaded file permanently
$targetPath = $targetDir . '/' . .$_FILES['image_name']['name'];
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_name']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
    exit('Failed to move temporary file<br />');
}
```

---

However, I wouldn't do this.

File upload is a very common task, and the generic code I use looks something like [this](https://gist.github.com/DaveRandom/4708126). Looks complicated doesn't it? Well, that's because handling file uploads isn't simple. However, what are that complexity does is provide a nice straightforward way to address the security concerns I outlined above. It has built in support for images, including options to resize then in a clean and easy way.

Let's have a look at how we might use it in your code:

```
$baseDir = './uploads';

// Very simple autoloader for demo purposes
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require strtolower(basename($class)).'.php';
});

// When you instantiate this the $_FILES superglobal is destroyed
// You must access all uploaded files via this API from this point onwards
$uploadManager = new \Upload\Manager;

// Fetches a FileCollection associated with the named form control
$control = $uploadManager->getControl('image_name');

// getControl returns NULL if there are no files associated with that name
if (!isset($control)) {
    exit('No file was uploaded in the image_name control');
}

// Check/create target directory
// You still need to do this, it's not magic ;-)
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', date('y-m-d'));
$targetDir = $baseDir . '/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day;
if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
    if (!mkdir($targetDir, 0644, true)) {
        exit('Failed to create destination directory');
    }
}

// This also handles multiple uploads in a single control, so we need to loop
foreach ($control as $image) {
    // You need to determine a file name to use, most likely not from user
    // input. This is a high-entropy low collision-risk random approach.
    $targetFile = $targetDir . '/' . uniquid('upload-', true);

    try {
       $image->save($targetFile, true, IMAGETYPE_ORIGINAL);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       exit("Oh noes! Something went badly wrong: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This does a lot of things in the background to address the security concerns I outlined earlier. It automatically detects that the image is of a valid, recognised type and applies the correct file extension to the saved file as well.

Answer (score 0):

One quick answer to potential code problems:

```
else{
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month);
}
```

This needs a second mkdir:

```
else{
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month);
    mkdir('./uploads/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$date);
}
```

After that, however - you end the code example with setting the `$target_path`

We need to see what comes AFTER setting the `$target_path` so we see what happens to the variable between being made and being output.

During debug, I recommend doing a quick output of its value to the log file immediately after setting it to see if it's OK at that point, but being changed later.

Comment: There's no change, after that I'm adding it to the database directly

Comment: Ah, useful information.  Still, we can't see that code, so we can't comment on it.  However, quick thought - what's the character limit on the database column this is being put into?

Comment: The character limit is 200

Comment: Well, then, unless you've got a really, really long image name, it's probably not running into a character limit... sorry, I'm at the limit of guessing.

Comment: No the all image name with directories is 24 charecters. Any way thanks